# Why subscribeOn method doesn't switch the context?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have this test based on [4.5.2. The subscribeOn Method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_subscribeon_method) (ignore the missing `new Thread(...)` part):

```java
    @Test
    public void theSubscribeOnMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        Scheduler s = Schedulers.newParallel("parallel-scheduler", 4);

        final Flux<String> flux = Flux
                .range(1, 2)
                .map(i -> 10 + i)
                .subscribeOn(s)
                .doOnSubscribe(sub -> System.out.println(
                        "[doOnSubscribe] " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .map(i -> Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", value " + i);

        flux.subscribe(System.out::println);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

which prints this (notice the `main` thread for `[doOnSubscribe]`):

```
[doOnSubscribe] main
parallel-scheduler-1, value 11
parallel-scheduler-1, value 12
```

Just moving `subscribeOn` after `doOnSubscribe` yields this result (correct from my point of view):

```
[doOnSubscribe] parallel-scheduler-1
parallel-scheduler-1, value 11
parallel-scheduler-1, value 12
```

According to the [Flux.subscribeOn](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) javadoc:

> Run subscribe, onSubscribe and request on a specified Scheduler's Scheduler.Worker. As such, placing this operator anywhere in the chain will also impact the execution context of onNext/onError/onComplete signals from the beginning of the chain up to the next occurrence of a publishOn.

so in this example I expect for `doOnSubscribe` to happen on a `parallel-scheduler` thread instead of `main` despite the place where I put `subscribeOn`.

Is this a bug? Why this happens and how should I fix it?

PS: using `reactor-core:3.1.0-RELEASE`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a bug. That's the expected behaviour. It's the order of the events which might be confusing at first glance.

I modified your example a little bit:

```java
Scheduler s = Schedulers.newParallel("parallel-scheduler", 4);

final Flux<String> flux = Flux
        .range(1, 2)
        .map(i -> 10 + i)
        .subscribeOn(s)
        .doOnNext(value -> System.out.println(
                "[doOnNext] " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + value))
        .doOnSubscribe(sub -> System.out.println(
                "[doOnSubscribe] " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

flux.subscribe();

Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Output:

```
[doOnSubscribe] main
[doOnNext] parallel-scheduler-1 value: 11
[doOnNext] parallel-scheduler-1 value: 12
```

When you think imperatively you would expect that the operators are called in declaration order, so the one which is below the other would be called later. This is usually true for functional/reactive programming as well but it's not always the case.

In the above example `doOnSubscribe` actually runs before anything else in your pipeline. It is the operator which gets notification about the subscription first and then it forwards the subscription to its upstream operator which forwards it to its upstream and so on...

So the events in the order they happen:

1. `flux.subscribe()` subscribes to the pipeline and triggers the execution on main thread
2. `doOnSubscribe` gets notification about the subscription and triggers the provided consumer on the main thread, then forwards subscription to its upstream
3. `doOnNext` gets notification about the subscription but it's only interested in the `onNext` events so other than forwarding the subscription to its upstream (on the main thread) it doesn't do anything yet(!)
4. `subscribeOn(s)` - context switching happens, every event after this happens in the context of the provided scheduler
5. subscription is forwarded to upstream operators: first `map` then `range`, both on the parallel thread
6. `range` is the source, so it emits the first item: `onNext(1)` on parallel thread
7. `map` is triggered on the `onNext` event, does the transformation and sends the transformed element as `onNext` event on parallel thread
8. `subscribeOn` doesn't do anything other than forwarding the `onNext` event
9. `doOnNext` consumer is triggered since it receives an `onNext` event, still on parallel thread
10. `doOnSubscribe` ignores `onNext` event, just forwards the event to the next operator
11. 6-10 events are repeated for `onNext(2)` item
12. stream completes

**TLDR**: The subscription event is propagated from the bottom operator to the top operator (`doOnSubscribe` and `susbcribeOn` triggered during this propagation in this order), after that the actual data is flowing in reversed direction from the top source operator (`range`) to the bottom.

Since `doOnSubscribe` runs before `susbcribeOn`, it will still run on the main thread.

Comment: It matters because in the subscription process it only affects the upstream operators. If you check the marble diagram in the docs, then you can see the different coloring of the subscribe arrows. That's what I tried to demonstrate in my answer by describing where context switching happens in the flow.

Comment: Hm, my comment disappeared. Based on the documentation, I quote: *placing this operator* **anywhere** *in the chain will also impact the execution context of* **onNext** I claim that `doOnSubscribe` placement shouldn't matter for my test.

Comment: Besides, the same documentation says: *Run subscribe,* **onSubscribe** *and request on a specified Scheduler's Scheduler.Worker*. It doesn't mention any special requirements related to the placing of `doOnSubscribe` other than that related to `publishOn`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but subscription happens upwards, by the time the subscribeOn operator takes effect the doOnSubscribe operator below it was already subscribed to and its consumer was executed.

Comment: Martin's answer is the correct one. See https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers for more details around schedulers, subscribeOn and publishOn