# Project Reactor's subscribeOn() doesn't affect onSubscribe() to be called in specified Scheduler as stated in JavaDoc

Tags: java, project-reactor

Project Reactor's Javadoc states
about method:

`public final Flux<T> subscribeOn(Scheduler scheduler)`

that

```
Run subscribe, onSubscribe and request on a specified Scheduler's Scheduler.Worker. As such, placing this operator anywhere in the chain will also impact the execution context of onNext/onError/onComplete signals from the beginning of the chain ...
```

I have next unit test

```
    @Test
    void testSubscribeOn() {
        // when
        var flux = Flux.just("alex", "adam", "andrew")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .log();

        // then
        StepVerifier.create(flux)
                .expectNextCount(3)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
```

I expect that logged messages will show that onSubscribe, request, onNext, onComplete will run in thread from parallel Scheduler.
But my test shows that onSubscribe and request are invoked from the calling thread:

```
16:09:21.286 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- onSubscribe(FluxSubscribeOn.SubscribeOnSubscriber)
16:09:21.290 [Test worker] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- request(unbounded)
16:09:21.293 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- onNext(alex)
16:09:21.293 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- onNext(adam)
16:09:21.293 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- onNext(andrew)
16:09:21.293 [parallel-1] INFO reactor.Flux.SubscribeOn.1 -- onComplete()
```

After posting this question I found related question [Why subscribeOn method doesn't switch the context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553733/why-subscribeon-method-doesnt-switch-the-context?rq=2) but as for me it still doesn't answer my question why in logs I see onSubscribe(...) and request(...) in calling thread instead of Scheduler thread as stated in documentation.

I don't have doOnSubscribe() whose lambda can be called in different thread dependending if doOnSubscribe() called before or after subscribeOn(Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

*subscribeOn* will affect subscription of the **upstream** flow. Therefore, the *onSubscribe* and *request* of the *step verifier* are not affected, as they happen *downstream*. Only the inner/hidden subscription to the flux is bound to the parallel scheduler. As this subscription is done on specified scheduler, its elements (onNext signals) are emitted on the same scheduler.

Therefore, if you change the position of the `log()` statement like follow:

```java
var flux = Flux.just("alex", "adam", "andrew")
               .log()
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
```

Then you wil obtain expected behavior:

```
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | request(unbounded)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | onNext(alex)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | onNext(adam)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | onNext(andrew)
[ INFO] (parallel-1) | onComplete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Moving log() call up really did the trick. But I still don't understand how. As per my understanding onSubscribe and request of the StepVerifier are still not affected. They are still called downstream i.e bellow the subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).

Comment: Indeed, the `subscribeOn` method won't affect them. What it does is add a hidden/intermediate subscription that will affect upstream signals. If you look at the figure provided in the javadoc, you will see that signals are drawn with two different colors: orange for the signals emitted through the subscriber controlled by "subscribeOn", and blue otherwise. You can notice that the original subscription is blue (therefore not affected by "subscribeOn"). But then, subscribeOn cause a second subscription to the original flow. This one is affected.

Comment: @MaksymZhokha: To rephrase my previous comment: When chaining operators on a flux, you potentially create inner:hidden subscriptions that are started when the overall chain is triggered/subscribed to. The javadoc of *subscribeOn* does not refer to the subscription you will trigger manually, but the one inserted at the current point of the assembly chain.